# D major Scale chord progression root in bass

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Hello I want to know the difference of this on the pictures I’m attaching. Suppose we have the D major Scale and I want to use the chord progression II- V7 Imaj7 (E-7 A7 Dmaj7) of course in D major. Now in the case of V7 or A7 in the pictures is used the root of the chord in the left hand bass. In one picture is used C#,G,B and on the other G,C#,E. On the picture that shows the G,C#,E order at the left is shown the A7 before converted to root in the bass in other words A, C#, E, G. Then what is the right picture to use the root in the bass for d scale major for A7? For me I think is G,C#,E but in other place say is C#, G, B. Why or what is the right here? These are the pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: For starters, I'm pretty sure the question is "how do I voice (or notate a specific voicing of) an A7 chord". It doesn't matter that you are (or think you are) in the key of D.

Comment: Where is the top example from? It *doesn't* show A7. As Richard states, it's A9, which is A7 with an added bit. But when something extra is added, it ceases to be the original. So, it's inaccurate to label it A7. The notes involved in A7 are A C# E and G, but E is often omitted. All are from key D. The extra B is the ninth from note A, thus A9 is the chord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain I understand your question, but part of it might be asking why there's a B in the top example.

The top example of `C♯ G B` is really an example of an `A9` chord, not an `A7` chord. It's missing the `E` because the chordal fifth can be omitted without any change in the implied harmony. `A9` is the same as an `A7`, just with an added 9th (in this case `B`) above the bass. If you put an `A` bass below that chord, it'll sound very similar to the `A7`, just with an added bit of color provided by the `B`.

Neither one of these two voicings is inherently more "correct" than the other; both are perfectly acceptable, and the determination between the two rests on a lot of factors: what comes before the chord, what comes after, what you personally want in your own music, etc.

Comment: Excellent. More clear. Then it means for a chord progression for D major scale, for example in these chord progressions: I VI- I (Dmaj7 B-7), IV V VI- (G A B-), it means in the last can I use G7,A7,B-7 instead of G A B- and I still on D major scale ok no matter if I use 7 or not right?

Comment: G7 means a G major triad with a b7 (a minor third above the 5). That would be F, which is not in the D Major scale.